# How can I display emoji character's if I am encoding a JSON file with UTF-8? (Python)

Tags: python, json, encoding, character

I am pretty new to programming in python and working with external files, but I am trying to load a JSON file.

When I load everything into a string, all of the apostrophes and emoji's and some other characters come out as " ***\ud83d\ude02***" . That was meant to be a laughing emoji for example, and the apostrophe's come up as " ***\u2019*** " .

When I am loading the JSON file into my python program I use open("messages.json", "r", encoding="utf-8").

Is there any way I can make it that all of those types of translations either ***translate properly***, or I could put a ***placeholder*** for them instead?

Comment: That is the Javascript way of encoding those characters, it maps to a unicode code point. Custom placeholders would be a very bad idea, as you will then need to look for them specifically.
The \u ifs followed 4 hex digits can be directly decoded to the Unicode codepoint, so is essentially a generalised and standardised placeholder.

Comment: `"\ud83d\ude02\u2019".encode('utf_16_BE', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf_16_BE')` returns `'’'`.